# TestFlight New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, app-store, wkwebview

Getting this error when i try to deploy to TestFlight:

```
ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. 
Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more 
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
```

I understand that i need to change all uiwebview in the ios folder to WKWebView. I'm not sure where to start and what need to be updated.

places where uiwebview got mentioned
[image]

here is podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'BorroUp' do
    # this is very important to have!
    rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
    pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
    pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket'
    ]  

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.39.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.39.1'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.39.1'
    # Stripe
    pod 'Stripe', '~> 14.0.0'

    # Install additional dependencies
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

    end

    # very important to have, unless you removed React dependencies for Libraries 
    # and you rely on Cocoapods to manage it
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == "React"
          target.remove_from_project
        end
        if target.name == "yoga"
          target.remove_from_project
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Consider raising the target OS version to iOS 13 so that none of the pods will use UIWebView.

Comment: I would start by removing the version restrictions from `FBSDKCoreKit`, `FBSDKLoginKit` and `FBSDKShareKit` and running a `pod update`.  You have ancient version of those Pods specified.